# Extending biholomorhpic functions on $S^2$ has a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $A = \{ \alpha_1,\alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4\}$ and $B = \{\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3,\beta_4\}$
be sets of four distinct points in $S^2$
and $f : S^2
\setminus A \rightarrow S
^2\setminus B$
is a
biholomorphic map. I need to show that f extends to a biholomorphic map
of $S^2$
onto itself.

Comment: If $\alpha_j$ is not removable, then it's either a pole or an essential singularity. What would that imply?

Comment: I am new to this subject, so excuse me, I have to do this step by step. First take a coordinate neighborhood $U$ of $\alpha_1$, say. Let $\phi$ map $U$ to a homeomorphic copy $W\subset \mathbb{C}$. We know that $f$ induces complex functions by considering homeomorphic copies in $\mathbb{C}$ of open sets of the Riemann surfaces. Do you mean what if $\phi(\alpha_1)$ is not a removable singularity under such induced maps?

Comment: On the sphere $S^2$ we can use very large coordinate charts: $S^2$ minus one point is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$. For example, we have biholomorphic maps $\phi:S^2\setminus\{\alpha_4\}\to \mathbb C$ and $\psi:S^2\setminus\{\beta_4\}\to \mathbb C$. Now $g=\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is a biholomorphic map of $\mathbb C\setminus\{\phi(\alpha_1),\phi(\alpha_2),\phi(\alpha_3)\}$ onto $\mathbb C\setminus\{\psi(\alpha_1),\psi(\alpha_2),\psi(\alpha_3)\}$. Try to show that $g$ extends to a biholomorphic map $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$.

Comment: But how do I show that $g$ does not have a pole at $\phi(\alpha_1)$?

Comment: For example something similar, $1/z$ is a biholomorphic map from the punctured complex plane to itself, but zero is a pole and this cannot be extended.

Comment: OK, you can have a pole at one of those points. But only one. If two of $\alpha_j$ were poles, the function $g$ would assume all sufficiently large values $w\in \mathbb C$ twice. Having a pole at some $\alpha_j$ is not so bad either: it still extends as a holomorphic map into the sphere $S^2$.

Comment: I see. If it's a pole then map it to the point not covered by the chart and it will be holomorphic looking at the other chart. And it cannot be an essential singularity since otherwise locally it wouldn't be injective.